# How can I compile for ghc-8.4.2 code that uses lenses inside StateT monad

Tags: haskell, state, monads, lenses

I tried to compile this small program from Gabriel Gonzales 2013 blog post "Program imperatively using Haskell lenses":

```
 {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

    import Control.Lens 
    import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
    import Control.Monad.Trans.State

    data Game = Game
      { _score :: Int
      , _units :: [Unit]
      , _boss  :: Unit
      } deriving (Show)

    data Unit = Unit
      { _health   :: Int
      , _position :: Point
      } deriving (Show)    

    data Point = Point
      { _x :: Double
      , _y :: Double
      } deriving (Show)     

    makeLenses ''Game
    makeLenses ''Unit
    makeLenses ''Point    

    strike :: StateT Game IO ()
    strike = do
      lift $ putStrLn "*shink*"
      boss.health -= 10
```

I get error:  No instance for (Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadStat Game (StateT Game IO)) arising from a use of ‘-=’

What imports are required these days?

Comment: Your example works on my machine. Which version of lens are you using?

Comment: I suspect you have multiple versions of `transformers` installed, and GHC tries using a different one from that which `lens` was built against. This kind of problem can be avoided by adding a `yourproject.cabal` file (easiest done with `cabal init`) and then using `cabal build` for compiling your file instead of GHC directly. Cabal-install will make sure the dependencies have matching versions.

Comment: I'm using the E.K big lens library

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one version of `StateT`. To find out which one you need you have to go to the Haddock docs for the problematic function (in this case [`(-=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html) and follow the links from its definition.

There are two monad transformer packages, called "[*mtl*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl)" and "[*transformers*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers)", so my first thought was that you might be using the wrong one. However when I followed the links from the `(-=)` operator I found myself in the [adjunctions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4) library, which is also by lens author [Edward Kmett](https://github.com/ekmett).

So to get `(-=)` and it's relatives, it looks like you have to import [`Control.Monad.Representable.State`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Control-Monad-Representable-State.html#t:MonadState) from *adjunctions*.

**Edit** Looking through the source for `Control.Monad.Representable.State` it seems to be re-exporting the `MonadState` class from the *transformers* library. So make sure that you are using that one rather than the *mtl*.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:-45--61-
It's re-exported in `Control.Lens` as well

Comment: `mtl` is irrelevant here, as it is also built upon the `transformers` library and using the `StateT` type from there. It merely adds the `MonadState` class, which `transformers` doesn't have at all.